# Unable to resolve Php vairable defined in a Database field

Tags: php, mysql

As per my requirement I want to implement the below scenario.
Have a table which has a field and in that fields Name META which has a value in which there is again defined a php vairbale say

```
<?php 
      $sqlnew = "SELECT * FROM  `SKXD`  Where id=1";
      $resultnew = $conn->query($sqlnew);
      $roww= $resultnew->fetch_assoc();
   ?>
```

Is the query and m trying to reolve a filed `<?php echo $roww['Meta']; ?>`.

Which is there in SKXD table Value of Meta field is another php variable define i.e  `<?php echo $roww['Title']; ?>`  (which can be of same table or another table for which I tried writing query in the field itself and also on the page. This is all on index.php.

Now when i see the output i see  `<?php echo $roww['title']; ?>`

I want to resolve the value for title field and display it.

Comment: Please post more code

Comment: ``` <?php 
      $sqlnew = "SELECT * FROM  `SKXD`  Where id=1";
      $resultnew = $conn->query($sqlnew);
      $roww= $resultnew->fetch_assoc();
   ?>```

Is the query and m trying to reolve a filed <?php echo $roww['Meta']; ?>.

Which is there in SKXD table
Value of Meta field is another php variable define i.e <?php echo $roww['Title']; ?> (which can be of same table or another table for which I tried writing query in the field itself and also on the page. This is all on index.php.

Now when i see the output i see  <?php echo $roww['title']; ?>

Comment: Are you asking how to evaluate some code which you've stored in your database? My question would be, why have you got snippets of PHP stored in your database? What is it that you are trying to achieve exactly? I wonder if there's a more appropriate overall solution to your requirement.

Comment: there is a section on index.php where i have to display some values 
Say fields A
Field B
Field C
Now these values are first added by an admin saved into the database and then displayed to the user.  Now what I want is add the code of all this section alongwith PHP snippets in another table and fetch that value of 1 field which has all these php snippets. and Just add that one variable on different pages to show the same results.

Admin o frequently update the value of A B C. And currently its the same code written all pages. any change needs efforts to update manually on all pages.

Comment: This should be controlled by some options where the admin can select which fields to display from a list. Then you store the configuration in the database. Your PHP code would then read the configuration, and use it to decide which fields to output from the query results. That's the way you handle this kind of requirement, not by putting bits of PHP directly into your database. So, as a really simplistic 1-field example, your "meta" field could contain simply the string "title", and then you could have `echo $row[$row["Meta"]];` as the command in PHP, so it selects the field name in the config

Comment: "the same code written all pages"...in that case, consider moving that code into a function which can be included on all the relevant pages - then can re-use the same single piece of code wherever you need it.